# Loading a webpack-dev-server asset in Node.js (plain V8 environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-dev-server, server-side-rendering, webpacker

I'm trying out webpack (in the context of Rails' `webpacker` library) and hoping to use the generated bundles for server-rendering React components.

I can fetch files from the local dev server just fine, but the problem comes when I load them into my server-side JavaScript context. (I'm using Ruby's `ExecJS`, backed by `therubyracer`, which is a Ruby binding to V8.)

Since the bundle is from webpack-dev-server, it includes a bunch of code for setting up hot module reloading. This code assumes that it was loaded from a `script` tag, so it does some checks on the page's URL. In a bare V8 context, there *is no* URL, so we get lots of errors, for example:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
```

Because it tries to read `self.location.protocol`. (`self` exists, but `self.location` does not.)

I'm starting down the path of mocking various DOM APIs to cause the errors to go away, but I wonder, is there a *proper* way to do this? For example:

- Can I get a bundle from webpack-dev-server *without* the HMR code?
- Can I bypass the HMR code in some way (other than adding lots of mocks)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer, but I found a workaround.

The client setup is done during a `require` call, so I'm using a regular expression to comment out that `require`:

```
client_require = /__webpack_require__\(.*webpack-dev-server\/client\/index\.js.*\n/
# find the client require and comment it out: 
dev_server_asset.sub!(client_require, '//\0')
```

Now, the setup code is *present* but it never runs! It's hard to understand and brittle but it *works* .